# Axis exception from tomcat6 webservice server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, axis

I am running Tomcat6 with Axis installed. 
I have webservices set up in the axis server.Everything works for couple of hours after the server start and then it throws the below exception for every new requests. Could anyone please help me with this?

```
'org.apache.axis2.AxisFault  
        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:146)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.sendUsingOutputStream(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:337)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:214)  
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:448)  
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:43)  
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)  
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:136)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:130)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:829)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:255)  
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:627)  
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)  
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)  
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)  
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:675)  
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: null  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:671)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.writeEndElement(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:282)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.MTOMXMLStreamWriter.writeEndElement(MTOMXMLStreamWriter.java:129)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.util.OMSerializerUtil.serializeEndpart(OMSerializerUtil.java:61)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:926)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:918)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerializeAndConsume(OMElementImpl.java:947)  
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMNodeImpl.java:471)  
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter.writeTo(ApplicationXMLFormatter.java:143)  
        ... 26 more  
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:366)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:432)  
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:347)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)  
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:89)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.write(UTF8Writer.java:139)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flushBuffer(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1103)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.fastWriteRaw(BufferingXmlWriter.java:1149)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.writeEndTag(BufferingXmlWriter.java:803)  
        at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseNsStreamWriter.doWriteEndTag(BaseNsStreamWriter.java:669)  
        ... 37 more  
         Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out  
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)  
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)  
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:154)  
        at        org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:750)

' 


enter code here
```

Comment: I am still trying find a solution for this issue. Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Found the answer                    “Unlike request session, SOAP session has a default timeout period; if the client does not touch the service for a period of 30 seconds, the session will expire. In this situation, a client that sends the old serviceGroupId will get an AxisFault. We can change the default timeout period by changing the server's axis2.xml as follows: <parameter name="ConfigContextTimeoutInterval">30000</parameter>”                                         from the link http://wso2.com/library/articles/axis2-session-management-part-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer “Unlike request session, SOAP session has a default timeout period; if the client does not touch the service for a period of 30 seconds, the session will expire. In this situation, a client that sends the old serviceGroupId will get an AxisFault. We can change the default timeout period by changing the server's axis2.xml as follows: 30000”

from the link

http://wso2.com/library/articles/axis2-session-management-part-2/